# Answer didn't load temporary

Tags: bug, android-app

[This](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/42247/15087) answer just didn't load when I opened the question for the first time.

[image: Just a blank space]

Reloading(by dragging down) didn't do anything, but when going back to the previous view and opening the question again, the answer was visible. I wasn't able to reproduce this bug since, and because of that I don't know whether or not it has something to do with the text itself.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: GT-I9505
- OS Version: 4.2.2 (I9505XXUBMEA)

Comment: can you replicate this issue in low signal areas? That's the only thing that seems to cause this for me.

Comment: @RoryAlsop If thats the problem, I don't understand why it still didn't work after reloading. All other answers were displayed correctly(before and after reloading). Or does "reloading" only apply to the question itself?

Comment: Yeah - if I knew the answer I'd have posted an answer - was hoping to just give some more anecdotal support. :-)

Comment: @RoryAlsop Yes, thanks :-). Haven't even thought about that the wifi connection could be the problem. Still weird though.